# How to make subplots from charts that are not matplotlib?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have a model learning chart for test values and training values. I can create a graph grid without any problem. The problem is that it's a huge amount of code. I would like to shorten the code and do it with a loop. below I will show which one

```
classifiers = [NBC,LRE,GBC,RFC,LGBM,CBC]

from plot_metric.functions import BinaryClassification

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4,ax5,ax6) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=6,figsize=(11,12))

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)

ax1 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, NBC, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

ax2 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 1:])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, LRE, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

ax3 = plt.subplot(grid[1, :1])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, GBC, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

ax4 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 1:])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, RFC, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

ax5 = plt.subplot(grid[2, 1:])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, LGBM, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

ax6 = plt.subplot(grid[2, :1])
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, CBC, print_model=False, style='ggplot')


ax1.title.set_text('GN')
ax1.title.set_color('blue')

ax2.title.set_text('LogReg')
ax2.title.set_color('blue')

ax3.title.set_text('GradBoos')
ax3.title.set_color('blue')

ax4.title.set_text('RandFor')
ax4.title.set_color('blue')

ax5.title.set_text('LGBM')
ax5.title.set_color('blue')

ax6.title.set_text('CatBoost')
ax6.title.set_color('blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is my loop that fails:

```
classifiers = [NBC,LRE,GBC,RFC,LGBM,CBC]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(10,6))

for cls, ax in zip(classifiers, axes.flatten()):
    
    ax.title.set_text(type(cls).__name__)
    ax.title.set_color('blue')
    plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, cls, print_model=False, style='ggplot')
    
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

How can I shorten my code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `plot_metric` package, but based on your code, you can try this loop:

```
classifiers = [NBC,LRE,GBC,RFC,LGBM,CBC]

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)

for i in range(6):
    col, row = i//2, i%2
    ax = plt.subplot(grid[row,col])

    model = classifiers[i]
    plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, 
                         X_test, y_test, 
                         model, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

    ax.title.set_text(model.__name__)
    ax1.title.set_color('blue')
```

Comment: Thank you Quang Hoang, you helped me a lot. Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Quang Hoang, you helped me a lot. Generally, there is something wrong in your code because the two models are mirrored - somehow. I don't understand why and what's going on.
Maybe you will look - I've modernized your code a bit, maybe you know why this is happening?

```
classifiers = [NBC,LRE,GBC,RFC,LGBM,CBC]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)

for i in range(6):
    col, row = i//3, i%2
    ax = plt.subplot(grid[row,col]) 


    model = classifiers[i]
    plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, 
                         X_test, y_test, 
                         model, print_model=False, style='ggplot')

    #ax.title.set_text(model.__name__)
    #ax.title.set_color('blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Check the line `row,col = ` should be `i//2, i % 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much - if you still have a little patience for me then take a look because it displays only 4 charts and you can't load the model names.

I made:

```
col, row = i//2, i%2
```

1. lack of two models (only 4 models visable)
2. ax.title.set_text(model.**name**) doesn't work

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
[image]